# scipy.stats.ttest_ind without array (python)

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have done a number of calculations to estimate μ, σ and N for my two samples. Due to a number of approximations I don't have the arrays that are expected as input to scipy.stats.ttest_ind. Unless I am mistaken I only need μ, σ and N to do a [welch's t test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test). Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As an update**

The function is now available in `scipy.stats`, since version 0.16.0

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats.html

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats(mean1, std1, nobs1, mean2, std2, nobs2, equal_var=True)
T-test for means of two independent samples from descriptive statistics.

This is a two-sided test for the null hypothesis that 2 independent samples have identical average (expected) values.
```

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a straightforward implementation based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch's_t_test):

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

def welch_t_test(mu1, s1, N1, mu2, s2, N2):
  # Construct arrays to make calculations more succint.
  N_i = np.array([N1, N2])
  dof_i = N_i - 1
  v_i = np.array([s1, s2]) ** 2
  # Calculate t-stat, degrees of freedom, use scipy to find p-value.
  t = (mu1 - mu2) / np.sqrt(np.sum(v_i / N_i))
  dof = (np.sum(v_i / N_i) ** 2) / np.sum((v_i ** 2) / ((N_i ** 2) * dof_i))
  p = stats.distributions.t.sf(np.abs(t), dof) * 2
  return t, p
```

It yields virtually identical results:

```
sample1 = np.random.rand(10)
sample2 = np.random.rand(15)
result_test = welch_t_test(np.mean(sample1), np.std(sample1, ddof=1), sample1.size,
                           np.mean(sample2), np.std(sample2, ddof=1), sample2.size)
result_scipy = stats.ttest_ind(sample1, sample2,equal_var=False)
np.allclose(result_test, result_scipy)
True
```

Comment: Perfect! Perhaps this could be added to statsmodels to resolve the github issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have written t-test and z-test functions that take the summary statistics for statsmodels.

Those were intended mainly as internal shortcuts to avoid code duplication, and are not well documented.

For example http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats._tstat_generic.html

The list of related functions is here:
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/stats.html#basic-statistics-and-t-tests-with-frequency-weights

edit: in reply to comment

The function just does the core calculation, the actual calculation of the standard deviation of the difference under different assumptions is added to the calling method.
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/stats/weightstats.py#L713

**edit**

Here is an example how to use the methods of the CompareMeans class that includes the t-test based on summary statistics. We need to create a class that holds the relevant summary statistic as attributes. At the end there is a function that just wraps the relevant calls.

```
"""
Created on Wed Jul 23 05:47:34 2014
Author: Josef Perktold
License: BSD-3

"""

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import CompareMeans, ttest_ind


class SummaryStats(object):

    def __init__(self, nobs, mean, std):
        self.nobs = nobs
        self.mean = mean
        self.std = std
        self._var = std**2

np.random.seed(123)
nobs = 20
x1 = 1 + np.random.randn(nobs)
x2 = 1 + 1.5 * np.random.randn(nobs)

print stats.ttest_ind(x1, x2, equal_var=False)
print ttest_ind(x1, x2, usevar='unequal')

s1 = SummaryStats(x1.shape[0], x1.mean(0), x1.std(0))
s2 = SummaryStats(x2.shape[0], x2.mean(0), x2.std(0))

print CompareMeans(s1, s2).ttest_ind(usevar='unequal')



def ttest_ind_summ(summ1, summ2, usevar='unequal'):
    """t-test for equality of means based on summary statistic

    Parameters
    ----------
    summ1, summ2 : tuples of (nobs, mean, std)
        summary statistic for the two samples

    """

    s1 = SummaryStats(*summ1)
    s2 = SummaryStats(*summ2)
    return CompareMeans(s1, s2).ttest_ind(usevar=usevar)

print ttest_ind_summ((x1.shape[0], x1.mean(0), x1.std(0)),
                     (x2.shape[0], x2.mean(0), x2.std(0)), 
                     usevar='unequal')

''' result
(array(1.1590347327654558), 0.25416326823881513)
(1.1590347327654555, 0.25416326823881513, 35.573591346616553)
(1.1590347327654558, 0.25416326823881513, 35.57359134661656)
(1.1590347327654558, 0.25416326823881513, 35.57359134661656)
'''
```

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for but the lack of documentation makes it hard to know for sure. Given μ, σ and N for each sample I want the p-value. statsmodels.stats.weightstats._tstat_generic seems to assume both σs are the same. I could implement the formulas on the wikipedia page to get t and v then use numpy.random.standard_t to get my  two-tailed p-value. Would I be duplicating code?

Comment: I edited my answer. In my version in statsmodels, the calculations are spread over several methods and functions, mainly so we can reuse the different pieces for different hypothesis tests. The easiest would be to combine the different elements into a function for the specific t-test, Welch's test in this case.

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused still. Could you provide a short code snippet showing how to go from μ, σ and N for each sample to a p-value using these functions.

Comment: What I thought about was just copy-pasting the relevant parts. However, the way the classes are written in statsmodels, it is actually easy to wrap them for use with summary statistics. I also opened an issue with statsmodels. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1843